Type Greek characters on the graph in a straight font
It is necessary to change the font from italics to a straight line in the axis caption, in the text on the graph and in the legend.

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[% 
            width=8cm, % Increased width for better visibility
            height=8cm, % Increased height for better visibility
            at={(0cm,0cm)},
            scale only axis,
            clip=false,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=6, % New limits for x-axis
            xlabel style={font=\upshape},
            xlabel={$\xi$},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=40, % New limits for y-axis to fit the parabola
            ylabel style={font=\upshape, rotate=-90}, % Rotated label for y-axis
            ylabel={$\delta$},
            ylabel style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,0.5)}, anchor=south east},
            ytick={0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40}, % Explicit y-ticks for new scale
            axis background/.style={fill=white},
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line*=left,
            xticklabel style={yshift=-0.2cm}, % Shift x-tick labels slightly downward
            every axis label/.append style={font=\normalfont},
            line cap=round
            ]
            \addplot [color=black, dashed, line width=1.0pt, domain=0:6, samples=100]
            {x^2}; % Plot y = x^2
            
            \node at (axis cs:2.5, 20) [anchor=west] {\textsf{\itshape $\delta = \xi^2$}};
            \legend{$\delta = \xi^2$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

In the comments, I received an answer that in order to change the font from italics to straight, you need to replace $\xi$ with $\upxi$, $\delta$ with $\updelta$ and so on.
Then I will get a graph in the form:

.
the font is straight, but the symbol is different from what we would like.
Below is an example of an image with the font that I need to get:


Please can you explain better your question please?

Are you looking for ylabel={$\updelta$}, etc.?

If the image comes from a PDF file use How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

I need a font similar to times new roman
